# October cms long load time for query

Tags: mysql, activerecord, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm trying to optimize this nested query which takes a very long time to load.

The basic idea is to get all the series that belong to a department, in the middle the're products that belong to many departments and many series. 
the table structure

departments*<-->*products*<->*series

In the models the relationships are defined as follows Department model

```
public $belongsToMany  = [
      'products' => [
        '\depcore\parts\Models\Product',
        'table' => 'depcore_parts_products_departments',
      ],
      // 'series' => [
      //   '\depcore\parts\Models\Series',
      //   'table' => 'depcore_parts_products_series',
      // ]
    ];
```

Series model

```
public $hasMany = [
      'products' => [
        '\depcore\parts\Models\Product',
        'table' => 'depcore_parts_products_departments',
      ]
    ];
```

The product model

```
public $belongsToMany = [
      'series' => [
        'depcore\parts\Models\Series',
        'table' => 'depcore_parts_products_series',
        'order' => 'name',
        ],
      'departments' => [
        'depcore\parts\Models\Department',
        'table' => 'depcore_parts_products_departments',
        // 'order' => 'name'
        ]
    ];
```

In the Department model I've created a method to retrieve all the series that belong to the department which after analyzing is causing some serious performance issues

```
public function series (){

      $seriesArray = array( );
      $products = $this->products()->remember(100)->get();
      foreach ($products as $product) {
        $productSeries = $product->series()->remember(100)->get();
        foreach ($productSeries as $series) {
            if (!isset($seriesArray[$series->id]) and $series->published )
                $seriesArray[$series->id] = $series;
        }
      }

     return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::make($seriesArray);

    }
```

I'guess this could be done with raw SQL or better implementation in the active record but I'm stuck on both.

I've added the `remember()` method later on but with no results. 
Right now the loading time for the webpage is about 20s. when removing this code ist instantly.

Any advice is appreciated.

From the table structure I guess this would be the apropriate SQL command (commands) to run in order to get the result needed

```
SELECT DISTINCT series_id FROM depcore_parts_products_series WHERE product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM depcore_parts_products_departments WHERE department_id = 3);
```

This query runs only on the intermediate tables and gets the right results (in phpmyadmin) of `series_id` (the department_id = 3 is as an example)

Using Hardik Satasiya code I had to change a couple of lines or the view would not show any series just empty lines.

```
public function series (){

        $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT series_id FROM depcore_parts_products_series WHERE product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM depcore_parts_products_departments WHERE department_id = :dep_id)';

        $data = ['dep_id' => $this->id];
        $query = \DB::select($sql, $data);
        $data = $query;

        $ids = array();
        // I had to rewrite this pare and make it more inelegant still 
        // but the refresh method appeared to made it step out the execution cycle 
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $ids[] = $value->series_id;
        }

        // in $data we are passing only id information
        // so this records have only id, not db all attributes
        // what ever you pass in $data will become model attributes if its in list
        $collection = \depcore\parts\Models\Series::hydrate($ids);
        return Series::published()->whereIn('id',$ids)->get();

    }
```

The block partial

```
<div class="element-grid">
    <h4 {% if hideChildren|length and departmentModel.id not in filters.departments %} class='inactive' {% endif %}  ><a href="{{ url('/')}}/parts?Filter[departments][]={{ departmentModel.id }}">{{ departmentModel.name }}</a></h4>
    {% if not hideChildren|length %}
    <div class="list">
      <div class="block left-block">
          {% if departmentModel.getChildren|length %}
              <ul class='departments'>
                {% for child in departmentModel.getChildren %}
                     {% if child.published %}
                        <li><strong><a href="{{ url('/')}}/parts?Filter[departments][]={{ departmentModel.id }}&Filter[departments][]={{ child.id }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li></strong>
                     {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
          {% endif %}
         <ul class="series">
           {% for series in departmentModel.departmentSeries.series|slice(0,10) %}
             <li><a href="{{ url('/')}}/parts?Filter[departments][]={{ departmentModel.id }}&{{ departmentModel.departmentSeries.childrenString }}&Filter[series][]={{ series.id }}">{{ series.name }}</a></li>
           {% endfor %}
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="block right-block">
             <ul class="series series-right">
                {% for series in departmentModel.departmentSeries.series|slice(10,length) %}
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/')}}/parts?Filter[departments][]={{ departmentModel.id }}&{{ departmentModel.departmentSeries.childrenString }}&Filter[series][]={{ series.id }}">{{ series.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="{{ departmentModel.image.file_name | media }}" alt="">
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

The departmentSeries scope.

```
public function scopeDepartmentSeries( $query ){
        $children = $query->getModel()->getChildren();
        // dd($children);
        if ( count( $children ) > 0 ) {
            $seriesArray = array (  );

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $childrenIds[] = 'Filter[departments][]='.$child->id;

                foreach ($child->series (  ) as $series) {

                    if (!in_array($series->id,$seriesArray)) $seriesArray[] = $series->id;

                    if (!array_key_exists($series->id,$seriesArray)) $seriesArray[$series->id] = $series->name;

                }
            } // endforeach children as child
            $childrenString = implode( '&', $childrenIds );
            return ["series" => Series::whereIn ( 'id',$seriesArray )->get (  ),
                    "childrenString" => $childrenString];
        }
        return ["series" => $query->getModel()->series(  )];
    }
```

Comment: ok some details required `Series model` => table `depcore_parts_products_departments` is `depcore_parts_products_series` right ? and next can't we add `department_id`  into series model so it will not create issue(not sure about your db architecture) but we can use this to avoid reference chain, series can direct point department instead going through products.

Comment: it is just my point of view may be you have some other use-case, if you have other use-case and above comment did not help then we can write `raw sql` just let us know so we can prepare `raw sql`

Comment: I was trying to avoid duplicating the many to many relations via departments<->series. So the are intermediate tables like you pointed out. Right now I would like to keep the structure as it is and use raw sql to get the ids of series from products.

Comment: ok i will try to replicate your problem to my instance and then try to build raw query for that

Comment: I've added a raw sql statement which works as it should - right now I'm having problem translating it into a lean active record implementation.

Answer (score 1):

you can utilize Raw queries and to convert `fetched id` in to model you can write this code.

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT series_id FROM depcore_parts_products_series WHERE product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM depcore_parts_products_departments WHERE department_id = :dep_id');

$data = ['dep_id' => 2];
$query = \DB::select($sql, $data);
$data = $query;

foreach ($data as $model) {
    $ids[] = $model->series_id;
}

$returnData = Series::whereIn('id',$ids)->get();
// dd($returnData);

return $returnData;
```

if you find any difficulties please comment.

### update

> my **department** model

```
use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\SimpleTree;

public $belongsTo = [
    'parent'    => ['HardikSatasiya\StackDemo\Models\Departments', 'key' => 'parent_id'],
];

public $hasMany = [
    'children'    => ['HardikSatasiya\StackDemo\Models\Departments', 'key' => 'parent_id'],
];

public function series() {

    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT series_id FROM hardiksatasiya_stackdemo_product_series WHERE product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM hardiksatasiya_stackdemo_department_product WHERE department_id = :dep_id)';

    $data = ['dep_id' =>  $this->id];
    $query = \DB::select($sql, $data);
    $data = $query;
    foreach ($data as $model) {
        $ids[] = $model->series_id;
    }

    $returnData = Series::whereIn('id',$ids)->get();
    // dd($returnData);

    return $returnData;
}

public function scopeDepartmentSeries( $query ) {
    $children = $query->getModel()->getChildren();
    //dd($children);
    if ( count( $children ) > 0 ) {
        $seriesArray = array (  );

        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $childrenIds[] = 'Filter[departments][]='.$child->id;

            foreach ($child->series (  ) as $series) {

                if (!in_array($series->id,$seriesArray)) $seriesArray[] = $series->id;

                // if (!array_key_exists($series->id,$seriesArray)) $seriesArray[$series->id] = $series->name;

            }
        } // endforeach children as child
        $childrenString = implode( '&', $childrenIds );
        return ["series" => Series::whereIn ( 'id',$seriesArray )->get (  ),
                "childrenString" => $childrenString];
    }
    return ["series" => $query->getModel()->series(  )];
}
```

> and **`page code section`**

```
function onInit() {
    $departmentModel = \HardikSatasiya\StackDemo\Models\Departments::find(1);
    //dd($departmentModel->getChildren());
    $this['departmentModel'] = $departmentModel;
}
```

> **and I am using `html/partial` you provided.** and it seems its working here

Comment: This is quite good still I had to make changes see ( the second edit ) as when using the refresh method the function stopped and in the view the items where gone.

Comment: Sure thing. Added.

Comment: thanks, you are using `departmentModel.departmentSeries.series` is it correct ? or dont you think it should be `departmentModel.series` as in my dev machine `departmentModel.series` works, and if its `departmentModel.departmentSeries.series` then please need little detail about `departmentSeries`. sorry for asking but need details to solve issue :(

Comment: yes the departments are in a simple tree structure. Don't worry about asking I'm glad for your help and to be honest on my way home I noticed that my edit is missing the function you asked about :)

Comment: ok thanks, I will add those things and test it, ha ha your question is 1 mile long office to home distance .. :)

Comment: I tested and it seems its working here, lets do `team-viewer` tomorrow and solve this, my skype id is `hardik.satasiya` please ping me, then we will coordinate

Comment: sorry skype is : hardik_satasiya